# Can I have multiple different ways of constructing a class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am making a class that has a config parameter and an optional parameter in its constructor.

The config parameter has a key with optional data object. There is an optional parameter that has a string id. I want the typeguard to only allow both or none of additionalStuffData and additionalStuffId.

```
interface Config {
    additionalStuffData?: Object
    otherConfigurations: any
}

class myClass {
    constructor(config: Config, additionalStuffId?: String){
        //Do stuff
    }
}

//This should not be allowed because ther *is* data but there *isn't* an id
new myClass({additionalStuffData: /*{Object stuff}*/}, undefined);

//This should be allowed because there is neither addidionalStuffData nor id
new myClass(/*Object full with other config*/, undefined);
```

In conclusion, I want to allow both id and data, or neigther id nor data. I don't want to allow just one of data or id.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is method overloads.

```
interface Config {
    additionalStuffData?: Object
    otherConfigurations: any
}

class myClass {
    constructor(config: Required<Config>, additionalStuffId: String) // overload specification
    constructor(config: Omit<Config, 'additionalStuffData'>) // overload specification
    constructor(config: Config, additionalStuffId?: String) { // general definition and implementation
      // do staff
    }   
}
```

Information about this language feature can be found [TS functions overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). Important to note is - arguments types of the definition need to contain all types used in overloads. So definition type needs to be the broader one and specifications(overloads) need to form a subset of these types.

Above is clearly visible in this example:

`Required<Config>` form a subset of `Config` as `Config` can be written as:

```
type Config = {
    additionalStuffData: Object
    otherConfigurations: any
} | {
    otherConfigurations: any
}
```

As you see `Required<Config>` is a first type in above union. `Omit<Config, 'additionalStuffData'>` also is a subset and is visible as second type in above union.

Second argument in the definition is optional, so it is binary type representing two states - there is an argument or there is not. That is why having this argument, or not having is a subset of optional argument.

Hope I helped.